# How to get the top and left coordinate of Visible Bitmap inside ImageView in android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am working on a Frame multiple layout selection feature of an Android App.

My requirement is to get the top and left coordinate of Bitmap after zoom and pinch the image.

I am using TouchImageView for Zoom and Move feature.

I have tried so many SO solutions, but didn't get the solution of my requirement.

**1st try -**

```
public static int[] getBitmapOffset(ImageView img, boolean includeLayout) {
        int[] offset = new int[2];
        float[] values = new float[9];

        Matrix m = img.getImageMatrix();
        m.getValues(values);

        offset[0] = (int) values[5];
        offset[1] = (int) values[2];

        if (includeLayout) {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();
            int paddingTop = (int) (img.getPaddingTop() );
            int paddingLeft = (int) (img.getPaddingLeft() );

            offset[0] += paddingTop + lp.topMargin;
            offset[1] += paddingLeft + lp.leftMargin;
        }
        return offset;
    }
```

2nd try -

```
            Rect r = img.getDrawable().getBounds();

            int drawLeft = r.left;
            int drawTop = r.top;
            int drawRight = r.right;
            int drawBottom = r.bottom;

            Logger.logsInfo(TAG, "Focus drawLeft : " + i + " : " +drawLeft);
            Logger.logsInfo(TAG, "Focus drawTop : " + i + " : " +drawTop);
            Logger.logsInfo(TAG, "Focus drawRight : " + i + " : " +drawRight);
            Logger.logsInfo(TAG, "Focus drawBottom : " + i + " : " +drawBottom);
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong, because i am working on this from last 3 days and still not done.

Thanks in Advance.
Suggestions really appreciated.

Comment: get `img.getDrawingCache()` you will get only visible. before this add `img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);`

Comment: In your first try did you try to use `Matrix.postScale(yourScaleFactor, yourScaleFactor)`?

Comment: You are resizing image by matrix. After `postScale` image get new coordinates so I think matrix.mapRect will help you. Get view rect and map with image matrix then left will point to your expected x.

Comment: @HarisQureshi Thanks for your quick comment, can you please tell me that how can i get the 'yourScaleFactor' ?

Comment: @Qamar I have tried img.getDrawingCache( ) but by this i am only getting bitmap (final bitmap after edit but **NOT the coordinates of my original Bitmap** ) 

Also Please share some code stuff which is related to matrix.mapRect ?.

Comment: Update your `ScaleListener.onScaleBegin` by adding `float startX = detector.getFocusX();  float startY = detector.getFocusY();` this may get you the focused coordinates of your zoomed image, give it a try

Comment: This works for Zoomed but when i fling the image the coordinates are not changing.

Comment: Have you try `RectF getZoomedRect();` for both fling and zoom case

Comment: @Qamar Now i am able to get the RectF(-443.5, 0.0, 1482.5, 1070.0) for Image and i stored this RectF in my local database.

Now i need to set the image on the basis of RectF. So how can i do that by using Matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `getZoomedRect` of `TouchImageView`

Add function and return `PointF topLeft = transformCoordTouchToBitmap(0, 0, true);`

Method signature

```
private PointF transformCoordTouchToBitmap(float x, float y, boolean clipToBitmap)
```

Passing `clipToBitmap` true mean visible rect

```
/**
     * Return a Rect representing the zoomed image.
     * @return rect representing zoomed image
     */
    public RectF getZoomedRect() {
        if (mScaleType == ScaleType.FIT_XY) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("getZoomedRect() not supported with FIT_XY");
        }
        PointF topLeft = transformCoordTouchToBitmap(0, 0, true);
        PointF bottomRight = transformCoordTouchToBitmap(viewWidth, viewHeight, true);

        float w = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        float h = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        return new RectF(topLeft.x / w, topLeft.y / h, bottomRight.x / w, bottomRight.y / h);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this but i am getting this  - RectF(0.90758044, 0.0, 0.9993077, 0.33333334)

Comment: And also how can i redraw that image by RectF?

Comment: Check out this method docs. Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect, RectF, Paint)